# Linear Temporal Logic Questions (2)

Tags: automata-theory, ctl

If you are not familiar with LTL (linear temporal logic), please skip this question! And yes, LTL is very significant to programming, as it is a core to the model checking system we use to verify programs.

Given these proposition symbols and their meanings...
Gp - always P
Fp - sometimes P

What do the following statements mean?

```
GFGp = ?  
FGFp = ?
```

I'm having a hard time with the logic surrounding LTL, and can't wrap my head around the above statements, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some terminology first:

Well-formed formulae are sentences in the logic that satisfy all of the combination rules. Usually there's an inductive definition of this to the effect that atomic propositions are well-formed formulae, and so are the following:

Combinations of well-formed formulae (WFF) with (replacing the usual logical symbols...) &&, ||, !, and => are also well-formed formulae. This is all standard FOL. (Linear) Temporal Logic adds a few more combination possibilities, so that F(WFF), G(WFF) and X(WFF) are themselves well-formed formulae.

Since F(WFF) can itself be a well-formed formulae, we can have F(F(WFF) as a well-formed formulae and so can G(F(F(WFF), and lots of other bizarre-looking agglomerations. But what do they mean?

Speaking personally, I find it useful to think in terms of sets of propositions for the complicated formulae, where G refers to a set of propositions, and F calls out a single proposition.  As you mention, given some current node, Fp means that p will occur in at least one of the successors of that node, and Gp means that p will occur in all of the successors of the current node.

So then, `GFp` says that every state (after this one) has at least one successor state where `p` occurs. So, `p` is guaranteed to occur (sometime in the future) after each operation.

`FGp` means that there is at least one state (after this one) whose complete set of successors is `p`. So there's a point in the process where it's `p`'s ever after.

Going further `FGFp` says that there's some point after which `GFp` holds. Again, `GFp` requires that `p` follows (at least once) from every operation, so the whole thing means roughly that sometime in the future we'll get `p` from everything (of course, this could mean that it's all `p`'s from that point forth or that `p` is just the last state).

`GFGp` means that the successor of every state is `FGp`. I suppose this means that every point in the path has some successor state whose descendants are all `p`'s (which seems close to, but is not the same, as the whole path is `p`'s).

Confused yet? I am.

Comment: Based on the book I'm using for the above, this all looks correct. And yes, I am confused, as are we all when it comes to this sometimes (it feels like) unnecessarily complex logic.

Comment: But also not complicated enough... :(  This logic on its current formulation is unable to convey graded distinctions like "Fp is possible", "Fp is unlikely" or "Fp is probable". You need something like generalized quantifiers (http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/generalized-quantifiers/) for that. Then there's vagueness...

Answer (score 2):

I think that

Fp means that P will finally hold (somewhere on the subsequent path).

So, GFp should mean that p will hold somewhere on the subsequent path, wherever in teh path you will be "standing". Or, in other words, p will hold in an infinite subsequent places of the path.

FGp should mean that there is a place on the subsequent path where p stands always from then on.

I'm not sure but GFGp could be proven the same as FGp

and FGFp the same as GFp.

Comment: Called consumption . BTW " in other words, p will hold in an infinite " places - I am not sure did any body tried LTL for continuum or any other uncountable flow of time, but for such logics it will not be true

Answer (score 1):

To make things easier to understand, I will use the alternative notation:

```
G = globally = [] = always
F = finally = <> = eventually
```

So []<>p means that p occurs infinitely often, i.e., it never stops occurring.
For example **p ******* p*****p***p***...

The formula <>[]p means that there's some place in the sequence, after which only p occurs uninterrupted.
For example ***ppppp...

Now <>[]<>p means that eventually p will be occurring infinitely often, which is exactly the same as p occurring infinitely often, i.e., <.[]<>p=[]<>p.

Similarly, []<>[]p means that from any point in time on, eventually always p.
But this is exactly saying that eventually p, so []<>[]p=<>[]p.

Answer (score 0):

GFGp = FGp example: all dogs eventually go to heaven, and some day will stay there forever

FGFp = GFp : sooner or latter all dogs go to heaven (and if they descend/reborn etc on earth they will go to haven again).